Visual Studio 2022 HResult E_FAIL error when trying to open a .net framework 4.7 web project
I am trying to open a .net framework 4.7 solution in Visual Studio 2022 v 17.10.5 and the asp.net MVC project will not load. When I remove the project and try to add it again, I get the HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. When I try to add a brand new asp.net framework 4.7 project, I get the same error. That leads me to believe that there is a problem scaffolding a .net framework asp.net MVC project.
I have tried the following:

Removed and reinstalled VS
Removed and reinstalled the Additional Project Templates
Deleted vs dir and .suo file
Deleted ComponentCache dir
Reinstalled the .net framework 4.7 dev pack
Deleted the projecttemplatecache folder and repaired the install

Appears similar to this...
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component in Asp.net MVC
And this...
Error after updating Visual Studio to 16.10, Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component
But there are no answers posted.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies>gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.dll
from
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXGQZrCFX6A
